# On android 7 app uses old version of WebView even after I installed up to date from Google Play

Tags: android, webview, version, user-agent

I have installed up to date version of "[Android System WebView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview)" from Google Play.
In apps I see both, the old one (as a system app) and the new one. I disabled the old one and rebooted the phone.
[image]
However app still uses the old WebView. (`User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SX500 Build/1.1.9; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/51.0.2704.91 Mobile Safari/537.36`)
Is it possible to force my app to use the new WebView version?

Comment: On developers options -> Webview implementation, what version is selected?

Comment: I have this option but it does not work on Android 7

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is not possible to do on the android app level.
It is only possible to do with root privilegies.
[More details here.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139413/android-system-webview-installed-but-not-used-by-apps/139415#139415)